# Focus on EditText is clear when click on it

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

My problem is when I click on EditText to input something, the keyboard appears, and the focus on EditText is disappeared, so I need to click again, and after that, I can type. What can be wrong?
Code in XML is easy

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_et"
        android:paddingVertical="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_phone_hint"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"/>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your `xml` code. Are you doing something with this `EditText` in your acivity or fragment file?

Comment: Nope. I do not do anything

Comment: Try to remove background from your Edittext, I am not sure it will change anything but just trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `windowSoftInputMode` to your `Activity` in your Manifest file. Set it to `adjustPan`.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```